# DDD and CQRS: use multiple repositories from a single command handler?

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

A canonical example of a simple e-shop.

Let's say a user adds some items to a basket and clicks "Checkout". A "Create Order" command gets issued. Now, before actually creating an order record with status "Payment Expected" and corresponding order lines in a db, we have to check that the items that the user selected are still available (maybe some items were available when the user added them to the basket but not anymore). And we also have to reserve them, so that they do not suddenly disappear while the user is still checking out.

So my question is how to perform this "check and reserve" routine? The way I see it I have multiple options:

- In the "Create Order" command handler use `ProductStockRepository` to reserve the products and then on success use `OrderRepository` to create an order. Meaning, we use multiple repositories in a single handler.
- Do not use `ProductStockRepository` in the "Create Order" handler directly, instead, create a `ProductStockService` and invoke methods on it to check and reserve the products. We still use multiple repositories in a single handler, but the usage of the stock repository is abstracted.
- Create an internal "Reserve Products" command and dispatch and await it from inside the "Create Order" command handler.
- "Checkout" button sends a "Reserve Products" command instead of "Create Order". In the "Reserve Products" handler we try to reserve the products and on success invoke a "Products Reserved" domain event. A corresponding event handler fires, in which we create an order.
- Some other way?

This is not a question about how to best model an e-shop checkout flow. The above is just an example. I would imagine there could be many similar scenarios in many different applications.

Comment: I understand that you want an answer to your scenario, but I'd like to point out that this is not how simple e-shops work. Stock is (almost) never reserved before the order has successfully been placed and paid. Consider that a good % of online payments fail. If you reserve the stock (which could be worth thousands of $ depending on what you sell) you could be losing legit customers due to an incorrect lack of stock. Also, stock levels in your software are most likely incorrect, as real items in the warehouse get lost, broken, etc. so you have to account for orders placed without stock anyway.

Comment: I don't actually write an e-shop, it's just an example that everyone uses. I just thought to ask a question about something concrete instead of an abstract thing. My real question is whether it's okay to use multiple repos in a single command handler or you have to use events all the time. I think in this situation it doesn't make sense you use an event, but I keep seeing posts about how events are always the way to go.

Comment: This won't answer your question but it's a heuristic. Eventsourcing has a tendency to force everything around it to use event sourcing too. The trick is to only use it where it makes sense and use a more traditional, simpler, easy to evolve approach in other places (such as classic DDD). Event sourcing systems are incredible difficult to grow unless you have the right set of aggregates and events from the start. This might be the case if one is rebuilding the same system for the 2/3rd time. There have been some papers in the last years confirming this, so caveat emptor when using CQRS/ES.

Comment: @Augusto using events doesn't necessarily mean using Event sourcing. My perception is that that most of the event-driven architectures don't use event sourcing, although I don't have the data to back that up.

Comment: Hi @FrancescCastells! Event Sourcing (ES) and Event-Driven Architecture (EDA) are 2 very different things (at least in my eyes). Event Sourcing is internal to the application (and it's common in applications that use CQRS or Actor Model) while EDA is a way to communicate amognst applications/services using asynchronous messaging. My comment above was aimed at Event Sourcing and not at events in general.

Comment: @Augusto you missed my point. What I meant is that the fact that the OP mentioned events in the question doesn't mean that it has anything to do with event sourcing, therefore I don't think your comment about event sourcing is relevant here.

Comment: @FrancescCastells you are very right! I read CQRS and assumed it was using event sourcing. Yet another example of how bad assumptions can be :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in other answers you don't want your CommandHandler to maintain multiple aggregates.  This should be delegated to a DomainService, achieved through DomainEvents, or pass the Products into the Order aggregate to maintain.  The solution also depends on whether the reservation process and order process are in the same bounded context or not.

**Reservation and Order in same BC, option 1 (Domain Service):**

- CreateOrderCommand dispatched

  - Infrastructure Starts Transaction

    - CreateOrderCommandHandler invokes CreateOrderDomainService

      - 1. CreateOrderDomainService retrives products from repository and attempts to reserve, throw on failure
      - 2. CreateOrderDomainService tries to create the Order and adds to repository, throw on failure
  - If no errors, Infrastrucure commits.
  - If errors, infrastructure aborts.

**Reservation and Order in same BC, option 2 (Domain Events):**

- CreateOrderCommand dispatched

  - Infrastructure Starts Transaction

    - CreateOrderCommandHandler creates the Order and adds to repository
    - Order creates domain event "OrderCreated"
    - OrderCreatedEventHandler retrieves product from repository and attempts to reserve
  - If no errors, Infrastructure commits.
  - If errors, infrastructure aborts.

**Reservation and Order in same BC, option 3 (Inject Products):**

- CreateOrderCommand dispatched

  - Infrastructure Starts Transaction

    - CreateOrderCommandHandler retrieves products used in order
    - CreateOrderCommandHandler creates the Order passing in all products
    - Order tries to reserve products using product domain entity, throw on failure
  - If no errors, Infrastructure commits.
  - If errors, infrastructure aborts.

**Reservation and Order in different BCs, option 1 (Domain Service):**

- CreateOrderCommand dispatched

  - Infrastructure Starts Transaction

    - CreateOrderCommandHandler invokes CreateOrderDomainService

      - 1. CreateOrderDomainService dispatched ReserveProduct command to Reservations BC and waits.

        - Reservations BC completes the reservation, throws on failure
      - 2. CreateOrderDomainService tries to create the Order and adds to repository

        - If failure, then compensate by dispatching UnreserveProduct command to Reservations BC, then throw.
  - If no errors, Infrastrucure commits.
  - If errors, infrastructure aborts.

**Reservation and Order in different BCs, option 2 (Domain Events):**

- CreateOrderCommand dispatched

  - Infrastructure Starts Transaction

    - CreateOrderCommandHandler creates the Order and adds to repository
    - Order creates domain event "OrderCreated"
    - OrderCreatedEventHandler dispatches ReserveProduct command to Reservations BC and waits.

      - If failure, then throw.
  - If no errors, Infrastructure commits.
  - If errors, infrastructure aborts.

*In all cases, use a concurrency token on the Product to prevent concurrent 'over-reservation'.*

Comment: In the scenarios where Reservation and Order are in different BCs are you proposing using distributed transactions? what happens if those BCs are coded with technologies that do not support distributed transactions?

Comment: No, with different BCs design should assume they are completely separate applications.  In Option 1, the Reservations BC will have completed the reservation, hence the compensation 'UnReserveProduct' on failure of Order.  The infra commit in all above cases is only for Orders BC.  For option 2 Order is added to repo, but not committed until positive result from Reservations BC.

Comment: But in that case your command is modifying two aggregates. What if the server crash after sending the ReserveProduct? That's why you don't change multiple aggregates in a single command

Comment: What you are doing in the handler is a process manager, and you don't want that to be during the request processing, because a process is a series of event (reserved on the other domain, cause a reaction in anorher one), that you want *eventually* to complete (also handling failures), but if you do it in the handler you cannot guarantee the eventually part in case of errors

Comment: Thanks, @rascio.  Appreciate the feedback.  Am keen to understand more.  So, client sees whole thing as a single step, so will issue one request to Order BC.  That remains a fact, in my view, as don't want client to have to manage the details of the process.  So, I have questions:  1) That request should be handled by a "Saga" instead of CommandHandler directly?  2) Then saga can persist current state of process and then, after crash restart, can pick up where it left off?  3) Requires idempotent function on Reservations BC?

Comment: And, it seems that we can't have client wait for whole process to complete before getting a response.  So, we create an Order with status "being-reserved" in-process and then respond to client before continue with process on server.  Client that then poll for status update?  Or another way?

Comment: This seems to be a decent summary:  https://medium.com/@lfgcampos/saga-pattern-8394e29bbb85.  Do you know of any other links that explore this subject further?  And thanks again for the feedback.  It has been a good lesson for me!

Comment: One of the important thing to model this was pointed out in the first and second comment on the main question. This is an example and not a real domain process. The fact that you have to raise a ReserveProduct command in the other domain is a domain business thing, it is not a techical decision, but a product one. In case you have the concept of a ReserveProduct in the other BC, yeah the Saga is the right way to do it, otherwise you shouldn't add it.

Comment: About your questions: 1) This is a implementation detail, you can send the command to the Saga, or the Saga can be activated after he notice the order was placed (an event, or some other trigger to simulate an event). 2) exactly, in that way you can say that eventually it will move the transaction in an "ending" state (success/failure), but it will not remain uncompleted. 3) Idempotency is very handy to don't care about retries that are an easy solution to recover certain situation, but in certain cases we can have different solutions.

Comment: About the client waiting for the whole process to complete, if you implement this as a process for sure you have to consider the case in which something happen and the order can be in that status, as the entire process is asynchronous to the client request. The polling solution is something to make the client feel this process as being synchronous, but this depends on the UI, and what experience you want your client to have.

Comment: The only thing is that also with polling you should not think that the operation cannot fail. I know this last part is not too much explicative, but it is a big topic that span a lot of layers of the software in looking at all the possible apporaches to do it

Comment: Thanks for your time, @rascio.  Very helpful.  Also, for OP (and me), this is a more detailed explanation:  https://www.infoq.com/articles/microservice-event-choreographies/

Answer (score 5):

The solution to the problem you present is not a matter of coding "style" or following good DDD practices. If using multiple repositories in a single handler solved your problem, I believe you should consider it a good option.

But the main issue in this type of scenario is that in many systems, Orders and Stock are in different Services/Bounded Contexts, therefore in different databases. Stock could even be in an external system not controlled by you. This means that you can't reserve the stock and place the order transactionally, so you risk reserving the stock and not placing the order or the other way around.

The reason why using events is recommended to handle these scenarios is because with events it is possible to develop this type of workflow reliably although this introduces new complexities. With a bit of technology, it is possible to reliably reserve the stock and publish an event and on the other side, reliably capture the payment and publish another event, then place the order and publish another event, etc. This workflow can involve things like outbox pattern, retries, sagas, compensating actions (to rollback the previous steps in case one step fails), etc.

Answer (score 1):

A command should update a single aggregate, otherwise you are breaking the "aggregate" contract, as far as this is true you can do how many reads you want in your handler.

Events are the most consistent solution for these kind of situation, but you pay the price of complexity to write your software in that way.

Should you use a repository or a service, this depends if the data you are reading are part of the same bounded context of the handler (repository) or in a different one (service).

Introducing a ReserveProduct command you are defining the domain behavior, and is a different issue on how to do things technically, you may want to do it or not, but this depends on the domain.