# C# Mediatr Request Handler Injected with multiple Repositories

Tags: c#, .net-core, design-patterns, mediatr

Im using MediatR in .Net Core and kind of confused if injecting multiple repositories to handle a business logics is an acceptable/clean way of doing it?

My sample Code:

```
public class MyRequestHandler: IRequestHandler<...>
{
  public IHeaderRepository _headerRepository;
  public IChildRepository _childRepository;
  ///constructor dependency injection happening here

  public async Task<...>Handle(.....request,..... cancellationToken)
  {
     var header = await _headerRepository.GetHeader(..headerId);
     if(header != null) await _headerRepository.Insert(...):

     await _childRepository.Insert(..., ...headerId)
  }
}
```

Comment: This isn't really a MediatR question. And whether it's acceptable or clean is subjective. You have a class that needs to interact with two dependencies (repositories) in order to accomplish something. That's not unusual. I wonder if your question is really about something else, like the relationship between the data in the repositories. But having a class interact with two dependencies isn't unusual at all. I'd be concerned if it had 5 or 10 or 20 dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are inserting just one aggregate. So you are not breaking "aggregate" contract. So as long as this condition is satisfied, yeah, it is eligible to read from other repositories.

However, I think, the way to go is events. So when header is created, then event should be published and then
`MyRequestHandler` should insert data by using `childRepository`.

Comment: thanks for the answer but when you say "event should be published", do you mean that i should create a seperate handler and call it in my "MyRequestHandler" class via mediatr.Send/mediatr.Publish?

Comment: @zxc I've found a really cool post. I think, it is what you can do [use multiple repositories from a single command handler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69692586). So it is worth to read other answers. If you really want to remove the second repository, then you can call domain service like in link.